# Torch tensors swapping dimensions

Tags: lua, torch

I came across these two lines (back-to-back) of code in a torch project:

```
 im4[{1,{},{}}] = im3[{3,{},{}}]
 im4[{3,{},{}}] = im3[{1,{},{}}]
```

What do these two lines do? I assumed they did some sort of swapping.

Comment: Does torch have constant table literals? Does `{} == {}` return true in torch? Because without that that's effectively no different then using `= nil` as the right-hand side of both of those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in indexing in the [Torch Tensor Documentation](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor--dim1dim2--or--dim1sdim1e-dim2sdim2e-)

Indexing using the empty table `{}` is shorthand for all indices in that dimension. Below is a demo which uses `{}` to copy an entire row from one matrix to another:

```
> a = torch.Tensor(3, 3):fill(0)
     0 0 0
     0 0 0
     0 0 0

> b = torch.Tensor(3, 3)
> for i=1,3 do for j=1,3 do b[i][j] = (i - 1) * 3 + j end end
> b
     1 2 3
     4 5 6
     7 8 9

> a[{1, {}}] = b[{3, {}}]
> a
    7 8 9
    0 0 0
    0 0 0
```

This assignment is equivalent to: `a[1] = b[3]`.

Your example is similar:

```
 im4[{1,{},{}}] = im3[{3,{},{}}]
 im4[{3,{},{}}] = im3[{1,{},{}}]
```

which is more clearly stated as:

```
 im4[1] = im3[3]
 im4[3] = im3[1]
```

The first line assigns the values from `im3`'s third row (a 2D sub-matrix) to `im4`'s first row and the second line assigns the first row of `im3` to the third row of `im4`.

Note that this is not a swap, as `im3` is never written and `im4` is never read from.